# Check in Map of list if exists value for specific key Java 8

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

In Java 7 I have

```
Map<String, List<String>> m = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
boolean result = false;
m.put("Name1", Arrays.asList("abc*1"));
m.put("Name2", Arrays.asList("abc@*1"));


for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> me : m.entrySet()) {
    String key = me.getKey();
    List<String> valueList = me.getValue();
    if (key.equals("Name2"){
        System.out.print("Values: ");
        for (String s : valueList) {
            if(s.contains("@"){
                result = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get în a bool result for `Name2` if it contains `@` using any match?

I tried using The following Code but I Don t know how to use IT for specific key

```
result = m.values().stream().anyMatch(v -> v.contains("@"))
```

Comment: Did you mean `if(s.contains("@"))`? (Double quotes, not doubled apostrophes)

Comment: You have `If` for `if` and `''` (two apostrophes) instead of `"`. Is this code supposed to be compilable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use `m.get("Name2")`, place the (nullable) result into an `Optional` and then use a mapping:

```
boolean result = Optional.ofNullable(m.get("Name2"))
    .map(l -> l.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.contains("@")))
    .orElse(false);
```

This is preferable to looping over the entry set, as `HashMap.get` is O(1) and iterating over the entry set is O(n).

Comment: the `map` should be `.map(l -> l.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.contains("@")))`

Comment: Better: `Optional.ofNullable(m.get("Name2")) .filter(l -> l.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.contains("@"))) .isPresent()`

Answer (score 8):

Do the following:

```
boolean result = m.getOrDefault("Name2", Collections.emptyList()).stream()
    .anyMatch(i -> i.contains("@"));
```

If the `Map` contains a correct key, check whether any of its element of the `List` as value contains the particular character. If the `Map` doesn’t contain the key, mock the empty `Collection` which doesn't contain anything at all and the result is evaluated automatically as `false`.

Edit: As @Michael suggested, using the [`Collections.emptyList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList--) is a better choice than `new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: This is the best way to do it. Why iterate over all of the keys when most maps are specifically designed to have a O(1) `get`?

Comment: @Michael Java 9 offers an in-between solution: `Stream.ofNullable(m.get("Name2")) .flatMap(List::stream) .anyMatch(i -> i.contains("@"))`

Comment: @Holger That's sufficiently different as to be worthy of its own answer, don't you think?

Comment: @Michael it’s different code, but not a fundamentally different logic, so I wouldn’t add an answer consisting of a small code snippet only. You can add it as an alternative to your answer, if you wish.

Comment: @Holger Hm, but most of the answers here aren't fundamentally different logic. They're all variations around 1 or 2 ideas. But that's up to you. I've found it interesting all of the subtly different ways that people have solved this problem, anyway.

Comment: @Michael I have no objections against all these answers, but I don’t want to add another one. By the way, I see a fundamental difference. There are answers doing a linear iteration over the map and there are answers which avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
String name = "Name1";
boolean result= m.containsKey(name) && m.get(name).stream().anyMatch(a -> a.contains("@"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
boolean result = m.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().equals(Name2))
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .anyMatch(s -> s.contains("@"));
```

Answer (score 1):

create a stream from the `entrySet()` and then provide your criteria in the `anyMatch`:

```
result = m.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .anyMatch(v -> Objects.equals("Name2", v.getKey()) && 
               v.getValue().stream().anyMatch(s -> s.contains("@")));
```

or using `getOrDefault`:

```
result = m.getOrDefault("Name2", Collections.emptyList())
          .stream()
          .anyMatch(s -> s.contains("@"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add correct filter condition:

```
m.entrySet()
.stream()
.anyMatch(entry-> entry.getKey().equals(Name2) && 
   entry.getValue()
.stream()
.anyMatch(string -> string.contains("@"))
.getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should filter by the required key, then you can use `anyMatch` to determine if the value of that key contains an element with a '@' character:

```
result = m.entrySet ()
          .stream ()
          .filter (e->e.getKey ().equals (Name2))
          .anyMatch (e->e.getValue ().stream ().anyMatch (s->s.contains ("@")));
```